# What does ":" mean?

Tags: c++

What is the meaning of this ":"symbol in cpp?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main () {
    std::string word;
    std::cin >> word;
    int H[1024];
    int big_h = 0;
    for(char i : word) {
        if(H[(int)i-97] > big_h) {
            big_h = H[(int)i-97];
        }
    }

    std::cout << big_h * word.size() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which book are you using to learn C++? It's very out of date.

Comment: `(int)i-97` ... please consider `i - 'a'`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Depends - maybe she/he just skipped the chapter where this kind of loop was explained? Would be a proof of doing so being bad idea, though...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `for(char i : word)`  it's not 98 out of date at least

Comment: @Aconcagua By the as-if rule I consider "having a book and not reading it" to be equivalent to "not having a book"

Answer (score 5):

`for(char i : word)` is a [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), introduced in C++11.

It roughly means *"iterate over every `char` `i` in `word`"*.

Comment: Note: this was added in C++11